# Collection of subclass objects that inherit (share) common superclass attributes

Tags: python, class, collections, attributes, datamodel

I'm trying to make a subclass to inherit attributes from its super, but at the same time,  the super stores a collection objects of the subclass. Here's my try but I'm feeling this is not an efficient way to do it and probably there's other much better ways to implement it.

```
class SuperCls:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.col = []
    def addSubCls(self, cCls):
        self.col.append(cCls)

class SubCls(SuperCls):
    def __init__(self, sp, c, d):
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        SuperCls.__init__(self, sp.a, sp.b)
    def __str__(self):
        s = 'a:{}, b:{},c:{},d:{}'.format(self.a,self.b, self.c, self.d)
        return s

sup = SuperCls(1,2)

sub=SubCls(sup,3,4)
sup.addSubCls(sub)

sub2=SubCls(sup,5,6)
sup.addSubCls(sub2)
sub3=SubCls(sup,7,8)
sup.addSubCls(sub3)

print '[%s]' % '| '.join(map(str, sup.col[0:]))
# printout:  [a:1, b:2,c:3,d:4| a:1, b:2,c:5,d:6| a:1, b:2,c:7,d:8]
```

Comment: What makes you think it is inefficient?  What don't you like about your solution?

Comment: the final project is intended to hold several nested collections

Comment: ... AND..1. These are my fist lines of python ever written, just newbbie concern. 2. The final project is intended to hold several nested collections and i found the referencing/calls redundant. 3. for the same reason, my original idea was to attach a collection of sub objects to the sup class and be able to use sup attributes as an input in sub methods.

Comment: This really isn't a discussion forum or a tutorial.  You should take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.    There is a lot being left unsaid regarding the design of your classes which might make a difference in implementation.  If you are using Python 2, you should really switch to Python 3.6+ while you are still learning.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot being left unsaid regarding the design of your classes which might make a difference in implementation.

Here is something ***similar*** to your implementation, it is a Python 3 implementation, and uses less lines of code which is more efficient in that respect. The subclass container is a class attribute of the parent; the subclass instances are added to the container when they are *created*.  The container holds weak references to the objects so that they can be garbage collected if/when they go *out of scope* or are deleted.

```
import weakref

class SuperCls:
    subclass_instances = weakref.WeakKeyDictionary()
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.col = []

class SubCls(SuperCls):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        super().__init__(a,b)
        super().subclass_instances[self] = str(self)
    def __str__(self):
        s = 'a:{}, b:{},c:{},d:{}'.format(self.a,self.b, self.c, self.d)
        return s


a = 1
b = 2
sub=SubCls(a,b,3,4)
sub2=SubCls(a,b,5,6)
sub3=SubCls(a,b,7,8)
```

These all print the same thing - each object has access to the container.

```
print(' | '.join(map(str, SuperCls.subclass_instances)))
print(' | '.join(map(str, sub.subclass_instances)))
print(' | '.join(map(str, sub2.subclass_instances)))
print(' | '.join(map(str, sub3.subclass_instances)))
```

`print(SuperCls.subclass_instances is sub.subclass_instances is sub2.subclass_instances is sub3.subclass_instances)` will print `True`.

Comment: Tx wwii, thans for the feedback, i will try to be more specific in the future.